# Машина состояний aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Для бота понадобилось в процессе "общения" сунуть машину состояний с одним полем `name`

Ниже представлены фрагменты кода, где я пометил места с ошибкой:

```py
class Register(StatesGroup):
    name = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"], state=None)
async def start_mes(message):
    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.from_user.id,
        text=start_var.format(message.from_user)   # Вывод сообщения из файла text_var
    )
    await Register.name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Register.name)
async def register_player(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Занесение в БД игрока
    """
    data = await state.get_data()
    name = data.get("name")             
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    text = db.add_player(user_id=user_id, name=name) # <-----Здесь ошибка
    await message.answer(text, reply_markup=menu)
    await state.finish()
```

**db.py**

```py
def add_player(user_id: int, name: str):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('list.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(f"SELECT name FROM Player WHERE user_id={user_id}")
    if c.fetchone() is None:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO Player (user_id, name) VALUES (?, ?)',(user_id, name)) # <-----Здесь ошибка
        text = f'Добро пожаловать! {name}'
        conn.commit()
    else:
        text = "Вы уже участвовали в этом проэкте,поэтому" \
               " у вас есть возможность продолжить"
    return text
```

и следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как мне решить эту проблему?**

Comment: в # <-----Здесь ошибка только результат ошибки парой строк выше: name = data.get("name") тут name становится None и потом бд не знает, куда инсертить

Comment: @Jack_oS а что поменять надо?

Comment: @Jack_oS присвоить name=massage.from_user?